# Disable Look Up from UIMenuController

Tags: swift, lookup, ios12

I want to disable **Look Up** when I double tap on my UITextField. Btw, the below code worked with **Share** but not for Look Up (I have also change the String of Look up to any possible notation but still not working).

```
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    
    if  action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:)) ||
            action.description.contains("_share") ||
            action.description.contains("_Look_Up")
            {
                return false
            }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}
```

Comment: I've printed actions' descriptions and get "_lookup:" for Look up

Comment: I totally forgot to put a breakpoint and print the remaining action value of the Look Up. Thanks, @ViktorGavrilov.